# save or save as text document ubuntu 16.04

Tags: text

i opened an empty text file in ubuntu and entered text in it. Now I want to save the edited text document, but my save icon is inactive. when tried to "save as" it say 
I don't have the permission necessary to save the file. please check that you typed the location correctly and try again.

Comment: Where do you want to save this file? In other words: is the path you are trying to save the file to writeable for your user?

Answer (score 1):

You've opened a file which you don't have permission to write. In another word, you opened it in read-only mode. Look at the title of the Text Editor, you can see **[Read only]** there.

If that file is for example in `/etc/` with name `abcd.conf`, you'd open it using this command in terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/abcd.conf
```

That will enable you to write on it.

However, I strongly recommend you to learn what you are doing in Linux. Otherwise, you might get an unbootable machine.